# Reference Request: proof that R-N Derivative is a ratio of PDFs for any two RVs on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, radon-nikodym

Consider any two continuous random variables defined on the Borel-measurable sets on $\mathbb{R}$.

I would like to reference a proof of the following statement:

*"The distributions of the two random variables are related by a Radon-Nikodym derivative, and the derivative is the quotient of their PDFs".*

I am looking for a text-book where the result is proven for the general case of any two continuous RVs.

Comment: What’s a pdf. By definition

Comment: R-N derivative against the Lebesgue-measure on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ and $g$ be the PDFs of two random variables with respect to the Lebesgue measure. Then, we may express them as Radon-Nikodym derivatives:

$$f = \frac{d \mu}{d \lambda} \qquad g = \frac{d \nu}{d \lambda}$$

where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure and $\mu$ and $\nu$ are two probability measures. The density of $\mu$ with respect to $\nu$ is then given by the chain rule for RN-derivatives:
$$\frac{f}{g} = \frac{\frac{d \mu}{d \lambda}}{\frac{d \nu}{d \lambda}} = \frac{d \mu}{d \nu}$$

A proof of the chain rule for RN derivatives can be found in Folland's Real Analysis, Proposition 3.9(b).

Comment: Thank you so much: which page is it on pls? I don't have the book with me and need to cite it, including the page.

Comment: @JanStuller page 91